# Google Map marker window

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add a link in my Google Map marker window. But my code only shows the marker and the window but it does not show the link.

I'm trying to add the link in this line:

```
$marker['infowindow_content'] = "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/$id',{$row->subject} on {$row->address}')?>";
```

when the link is clicked it go to some function of my index controller.
but why the link is not appearing in the window.

controller:

```
                   function index()
{


    if(empty($_POST)){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->googlemaps->initialize();
    $marker = array();
    //$this->main_model->get_map();

    if($result = $this->main_model->ll()){
        //var_dump($result);
        foreach($result->result() as $row) {
            //var_dump($row);
            //$data[]=$row;
             $marker['position'] = "{$row->lat},{$row->lng}";
             $id=$row->id;
             $marker['infowindow_content'] = "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/$id',{$row->subject} on {$row->address}')?>";

             $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
             //var_dump($marker['position ']);
             $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
        }
    }


    //$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    $data['list'] = $this->main_model->getdata();
    $this->load->view('main_view',$data);
} 


}
```

Model:

```
 public function ll($id = '')
    {

    $sql = $this->db->get('info');
    if ($sql->num_rows () >0) {
        return $sql;
    }
    else{
        return null;

    }
          }
```

The generated html from my code(the map part only):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map; // Global declaration of the map
        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Global declaration of the infowindow
        var lat_longs = new Array();
        var markers = new Array();
        function initialize() {

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.84815, 24.14670);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.85051,24.14529);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_0 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_0.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/1',street problem on something home)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.84931,24.14555);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_1 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_1.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/2',hello on 11 some)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_1, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.84858,24.14160);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_2 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_2.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/3',problem street on 78900 street)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_2, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.85000,24.14773);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_3 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_3.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/4',gulshan street on 11 gulshan)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_3, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.84620,24.14593);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_4 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_4.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/5',broken road on banani)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_4, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(65.84961,24.15164);

        var markerOptions = {
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map,
            animation:  google.maps.Animation.DROP      
        };
        marker_5 = createMarker(markerOptions);

        marker_5.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/6',no lamp on arbritary)?>");

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_5, "click", function() {
            iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
            iw.open(map, this);

        });


        }


    function createMarker(markerOptions) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        markers.push(marker);
        lat_longs.push(marker.getPosition());
        return marker;
    }

        window.onload = initialize;

        //]]>
```

Comment: We need to see more code... what do you do with 'infowindow_content' for instance?

Comment: 'infowindow_content' takes in the string value that you wanna show in the marker window..If u write "hi"there the marker window shows hi. Instead of plain "hi" i want to add hi as a click able link.

Comment: @martan you can feed html codes into the info window.  perhaps with `<a href="somewhere.com">hi</a>`.  Also are you using zend framework?

Comment: @kjy112.i'm using codeigniter framework and i've tried with html codes also..but in that case when i click on the link i keeps coming back to the same page instead of going to another page.

Comment: @martan can you post the generated html from your output?

Comment: @kjy112 sorry for my late reply..the generated html is given above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
$marker['infowindow_content'] = "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/$id',{$row->subject} on {$row->address}')?>";
```

The content for an InfoWindow is a string containing the actual HTML code. In your case, the `<?php` block is ignored as you can see in the generated HTML:

```
marker_0.set("content", "<?php echo anchor('index/get_by_id/1',street problem on something home)?>");
```

It has to be :

```
marker_0.set("content", "<a href='index/get_by_id/1'>street problem on something home</a>");
```

Try this:

```
<?php
    $subject = $row->subject;
    $address = $row_>address;
?>

var index = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
var subject = '<?php echo $subject; ?>';
var address = '<?php echo $address; ?>';

$marker['infowindow_content'] = "<a href='index/get_by_id/" + index + "'>" + subject + " on " + address + "</a>";
```